# Articulations : which technique to use on small constructions for sturdiness?

Tags: building

So I have been using *LEGO®* for a rather long time and over the years, I started going towards small constructions. While doing this, I began building rather small robots (*Mobile Frames* for those who know), between ~8cm and ~11cm or approximately 8 to 11 studs.

Those mechs I build are articulated and I want them to have as many articulations as possible (*e.g.* a leg should have a hip, a knee and an ankle, not only a hip). 
The problem is the sturdiness of the whole construction. I have tried multiple options and the articulations are often either too weak to stay in position correctly or too fragile to support other parts, leading to structure vulnerability and eventually *destruction* of either portions of or the whole robot.

My question is the following : do you know any **compact yet sturdy articulation building technique** or any small articulation part ? 
Bonus : if you can provide a method allowing me to build more or less *on* the articulation (not sure if that's very clear).

---

*EDIT* : For posing reasons, the articulation needs to have some 'friction' to keep a specific angle.

---

Should there be any problem with the question (wrong formulation, bad English, need for clarification), please don't hesitate to point it out.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer your question, hence the comment as opposed to an answer, but for larger constructions the 24-tooth clutch gear works well.

Comment: Well, building tricks are always welcome, especially when it comes to _LEGO®_.

Answer (score 5):

The [AT-ST & Endor (9679)](http://brickset.com/sets/9679-1/AT-ST-Endor) uses cogged connectors ([4210884](http://brickset.com/parts/4210884) + [4211803](http://brickset.com/parts/4211803), I don't know if the combination of both parts has a name) for the legs. These connectors are pretty strong for their size, they may be sturdy enough for your model if it's not too heavy.

[image]

---

For bigger constructions and higher degrees of freedom, beam with balls and cups can be used, they allow rotations and movements in two axis. For example, the [*Beam A 5M Ball/Cup Ø10.2*](http://brickset.com/parts/4593555) (they are other [similar parts on Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&catString=749&catType=P&v=1)):

[image]

For example, [General Grievous (75112)](http://brickset.com/sets/75112-1/General-Grievous) arms and legs can be adjusted in many ways:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is already a good start. However, I also need parts moving on multiple axis (like a human hip or shoulder for example). Any suggestion ?

Comment: @z3r0 I added the balls and cups, I hope that it won't be too big for your models.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately those parts are _way_ too big for what I intend to do. Do you happen to know any alternative ? Other than that, the cogged connectors seem a rather interesting concept for mono-axis (is it even English ?) articulation.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the plate ball and cup joints like [6043656](http://brickset.com/parts/6043656) and [4329654](http://brickset.com/parts/4239654) (and a few other parts with balls that will fit)

These parts:
[image]

One caveat though, brick #2 from the left does not have much sturdiness in holding joints together. 1, 3, and 6 are good though.

Comment: The two small ones in the middle of the picture seem to have size characteristics close to what I'm looking for. Do you happen to know if that specific ball-cup combination has friction (allowing specific poses) ? If I remember correctly, the other ones don't. Also, do you know if the 1x1x1 ball holder also comes in different shapes (1x2x1 like its left neighbour) ?

Comment: @z3r0 From experience, the two in the middle do have enough friction, however, there is no 1x2x1 for that piece.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll try to find some ball-cup combination somewhere to test their _friction_. Could you please write the designation of the two parts in the middle ?

Comment: @z3r0 14704 for the 2x2x1 socket and 3614 for the 1x1x1 with ball.

Comment: In my experience, #5 from the left, when paired with #1 or #6, has no friction worth mentioning.  I don't know about the other pairings.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best technique for building a sturdy Lego structure is to start with a wide and big base and then stack up with smaller bricks. I took part in a Lego challenge and one of the challenges was to build a big Lego tower. So, I decided to start with a big base. Then, I built up with smaller bricks. When I did my test to see which was the best, I found out that a bigger base is better. I also am doing a science fair on which Lego structure is strongest when dropped. I haven't done it yet but I believe that a square base will be the strongest instead of the other bases I have chosen. I love building with Legos but a big pet-peeve is when they break. That is why I am doing my science fair experiment to see which structure is the best. I will let you know when I have my data.